# SelectField producing [Not a valid choice] error when I try submitting the form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

forms.py

```py
class myForm(FlaskForm):
     ...
     time = SelectField('Hour', choices=[(8, "8AM"), (9,"9AM"), (10,"10AM"), (11,"11AM"), (12,"12PM"), (13,"1PM"), (14,"2PM"), (15,"3PM"), (16,"4PM"), (17,"5PM"), (18,"6PM")])
     ...
```

routes.py

```py
form = RequestCalendarAppointment()
if form.validate_on_submit():
     print('Form validated')
```

form.html

```html
...
<p>
     {{ form.time.label() }}<br>
     {{ form.time() }}
     {% for error in form.time.errors %}
     <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
     {% endfor %}
</p>
...
```

All my StringFields and IntegerFields work; however, I get `[Not a valid choice]` error in my HTML page when I try submitting the form for the time SelectField. I want the "8AM" to display in the html page (which it is) and to save the 8 in form.time.data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SelectedField choices I used strings instead of integers